# How do search through a numpy array to find a corresponding value of two coordinates?

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy

I have an array which has 3 columns: X, Y, and velocity. How do I write a function such that I can search through the array by inputting the X,Y coordinates and the function returns the corresponding velocity value for that index? 
Let's say my array is the following:

```
srcxy_deltv = [[2500 0 3.4123]
              [23000 0 3.4213]
              [23500 0 3.4303]
              ...
              [33675 25500 0.49377]
              [33725 25500 0.49878]
              [33775 25500 0.50381]]
```

The first column is the X, second coordinate is the Y and third is the velocity. I want to be able to feed both X and Y values into the function to return the velocity. For example:

```
srcxy(2500,0)
```

That should return the value 3.4123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a lookup like this:

```
srcxy_deltv = np.array(srcxy_deltv)

def srcxy(x,y, data=srcxy_deltv):
    return srcxy_deltv[(srcxy_deltv[:,:2] == [2500,0]).all(1),-1][0]

srcxy(2500,0)
# 3.4123
```

If you are open for other packages, `pandas` can be a good choice:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(srcxy_deltv).set_index([0,1])

df.loc[(2500,0)].iloc[0]
# 3.4123

df.loc[(33725, 25500)].iloc[0]
# 0.49878
```

Comment: Thanks man, exactly what I needed! Just had to change == [2500, 0] to == [x, y] :)